# How can I cure sickness?

Tags: adom

I made the mistake of eating a Kobold corpse and got sick. My health stopped increasing over time as a result of this, and it lasted for quite a long time. That character is long dead now, but it would still be useful to know for future reference how exactly I should go about curing sickness.

Does sickness wear off over time? If not, how can I cure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options: Blessed Potions of Healing can do the trick. Jharod will also cure sickness a few times. Praying may also work; don't take my word on that as I haven't actively played the game in years. I was certain there was at least one other method, but I can't find any reference in the ADOM Guidebook... Active-using the Healing skill, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

To complement izzy's answer, praying indeed cures sickness, as well as eating curaria mancox herbs. Sickness does wear off over time too, but it takes ages and it's not worth the wait. Finally, one possible effect of drinking from pools is curing sickness.